# add an attribute in an element that is parent of a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an object but I am facing some issues regarding the attributes of a parent element that contains an array.

I have the following xml structure and I can't add the attribute in RatePlans element.

```
<Root>
<RatePlans Attribute="??this one??">
    <RatePlan Attribute1="RPC" Attribute2="MC" Attribute3="RPT">
        .
        .
        .
    </RatePlan>
    <RatePlan Attribute1="RPC2" Attribute2="MC3" Attribute3="RPT4">
        .
        .
        .
    </RatePlan>
</RatePlans>
</Root>
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
namespace XmlT {
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root {
        public List<RatePlan> RatePlans { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace XmlT {
[Serializable]
public class RatePlan {


    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RatePlanCode { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MarketCode { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RatePlanType { get; set; }
}
}
```

This gives me a correct structure but I don't know how to add the attribute I want

**Another approach**

I've tried also another approach but this gives me wrong  values at all.

```
namespace XmlT {
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root {
        public RatePlans RatePlans { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace XmlT {
[Serializable]
public class RatePlans {

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string HotelCode { get; set; }

    public List<RatePlan> RatePlan { get; set; }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

this the method that I am using for the serialization

```
protected static string Serialize<T>(object objToXml, bool IncludeNameSpace = false) where T : class {
        StreamWriter stWriter = null;
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer;
        string buffer;
        try {
            xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            stWriter = new StreamWriter(memStream);
            if (!IncludeNameSpace) {

                var xs = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

                xs.Add("", "");
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stWriter, objToXml, xs);
            } else {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stWriter, objToXml);
            }
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer());
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
            throw Ex;
        } finally {
            if (stWriter != null) stWriter.Close();
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Does anyone know how could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If the `RatePlans` class from the 2nd example inherits from `List<RatePlan>` you will get the desired result:</s>

```
[Serializable]
public class RatePlans: List<RatePlan>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string HotelCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**:

My bad. Fields of classes inheriting from collections will not be serialized. I didn't knew that. Sorry...

However, this solution works:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class Root 
{
    public RatePlans RatePlans { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class RatePlans
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string HotelCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("RatePlan")]
    public List<RatePlan> Items = new List<RatePlan>();
}
```

Comment: have a look in my post, I've posted the method that I am using for the serialization

Comment: Updated my answer. First shot was completely wrong. Sorry for that.